# In python, questions on importing a module that import another module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a python beginne, and am currently learning import modules in python.
So my question is:
Suppose I currently have three python files, which is module1.py, module2.py, and module3.py;

In module1.py:

```
def function1():
    print('Hello')
```

In module2.py, in order to use those functions in module1.py:

```
import module1

#Also, I have some other public functions in this .py file
def function2():
    print('Goodbye')

#Use the function in module1.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    module1.function1();
    function2();
```

In module3.py, I would like to use both the functions from module1.py and module2.py.

```
import module1
import module2

def function3():
    print('Nice yo meet you');

if __name__ == '__main__':
   module1.function1()
   function3()
   module2.function2()
```

Seems like it works. But my questions are mainly on module3.py. The reason is that in module3.py, I imported both module1 and module2. However, module1 is imported by module2 already. I am just wondering if this is a good way to code? Is this effective? Should I do this? or Should I just avoid doing this and why?

Thank you so much. I am just a beginner, so if I ask stupid questions, please forgive me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no problem if you avoid circular imports, that is you never import a module that itself imports the current importing module.

A module does not see the importer namespace, so imports in the importer code don't become globals to the imported module.

Also module top-level code will run on first import only.

---

Edit 1:

I am answering Filipe's comments here because its easier.

"There will be no problem if you avoid circular imports" -> This is incorrect, python is fine with circular imports for the most part."

The fact that you sensed some misconception of mine, doesn't make that particular statement incorrect. It is correct and it is good advice.

(Saying it's fine for the most part looks a bit like saying something will run fine most of time...)

I see what you mean. I avoid it so much that I even thought your first example would give an error right away (it doesn't). You mean there is no need to avoid it because most of the time (actually given certain conditions)  Python will go fine with it. I am also certain that there are cases where circular imports would be the easiest solution. That doesn't mean we should use them if we have a choice. That would promote the use of a bad architecture, where every module starts depending on every other.

It also means the coder has to be aware of the caveats.

This link I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/comp.lang.python/HYChxtsrhnw#!topic/comp.lang.python/HYChxtsrhnw) in SO states some of the worries about circular imports.

The previous link is somewhat old so info can be outdated by newer Python versions, but [import confusion](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports) is even older and still apllies to 3.6.2.

The example you give works well because relevant or initialization module code is wrapped in a function and will not run at import time. Protecting code with an `if __name__ == "__main__":` also removes it from running when imported.

Something simple like this (the same example from effbot.org) won't work (remember OP says he is a beginner):

```
# file y.py
import x

x.func1()


# file x.py
import y

def func1():
    print('printing from x.func1')
```

On your second comment you say:
"This is also incorrect. An imported module will become part of the namespace"

Yes. But I didn't mention that, nor its contrary. I just said  that an imported module code doesn't know the namespace of the code making the import.

To eliminate the ambiguity I just meant this:

```
# w.py
def funcw():
    print(z_var)

# z.py
import w

z_var = 'foo'
w.funcw() # error: z_var undefined in w module namespace
```

Running `z.py` gives the stated error. That's all that I meant.

Now going further, to get the access we want, we go circular...

```
# w.py
import z # go circular

def funcw():
    '''Notice that we gain access not to the z module that imported
       us but to the z module we import (yes its the same thing but
       carries a different namespace). So the reference we obtain
       points to a    different object, because it really is in a
       different namespace.'''

    print(z.z_var, id(z.z_var))
```

...and we protect some code from running with the import:

```
# z.py
import w

z_var = ['foo']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(z_var, id(z_var))
    w.funcw()
```

By running `z.py` we confirm the objects are different (they can be the same with immutables, but that is python kerning - internal optimization, or implementation details - at work):

```
['foo'] 139791984046856
['foo'] 139791984046536
```

Finally I agree with your third comment about being explicit with imports.

Anyway I thank your comments. I actually improved my understanding of the problem because of them (we don't learn much about something by just avoiding it).

Comment: "There will be no problem if you avoid circular imports" -> This is incorrect, python is fine with circular imports for the most part. For instance, if module1.py has `import module3` and function1 calls `module3.function3()` everything will work fine.

Comment: "A module does not see the importer namespace, so imports in the importer code don't become globals to the imported module." -> This is also incorrect. An imported module will become part of the namespace. So in module3.py you could call function1 using `module2.module1.function1()` even without importing module1.

Comment: Having said that, making the dependencies explicit is a good advice. It is better to avoid referring to a module through another module that imports it.